# Unable to install epdfinfo on Emacs 28.1

Tags: compilation, pdf-tools

Running Doom Emacs 3.0.0-alpha on Emacs 28.1 on Manajaro with all the latest updates installed.

When I `M-x pdf-tools-install RET` it fails to compile. The following is the output of the command:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1/pdf-tools/build/server/" -*-
Comint started at Mon Jun  6 20:39:41

/home/sandip/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1/pdf-tools/build/server/autobuild -i /home/sandip/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1/pdf-tools/
---------------------------
    Installing packages    
---------------------------
Skipping package installation (already installed)

---------------------------
 Configuring and compiling 
---------------------------
./configure -q --bindir=/home/sandip/.emacs.d/.local/straight/build-28.1/pdf-tools/ && make clean && make -s
configure: error: cannot find necessary  poppler-private header (see README.org)
===========================
     Build failed.  ;o(    
===========================
Note: maybe try the '-d' option.

Comint exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Jun  6 20:39:44
```

I looked for but could not find any poppler-private package.

How do I install pdf-tools?

Comment: On debian, you need to install `libpoppler-private-dev`, I guess.  What OS are you using?

Comment: In fact, the requirement to install `libpoppler-private` was removed from `pdf-tools` 16 days ago.  I suggest installing an updated `pdf-tools` from melpa or straight (you see what I did there?) from https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools

Comment: @FranBurstall Thanks. I am using Manjaro linux. I have updated the question to include this information.

Comment: @deskmukh, did you installed first the Doom’s ```pdf``` module? See also this file: ```~/.emacs.d/modules/tools/pdf/README.org, to know what to expect in this installation.

Comment: @Ian Yes. Doom's `pdf` module was installed. I removed and reinstalled it. And I had gone through that file. But nothing there helped me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have all the needed tools to build? aka C compiler (gcc), make, automake, autoconf. Inside the folder ```pdf-tools``` there is a README file, some mandatory libraries to use - poppler library seems to need to have an ```-dev``` suffix.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Yes. I have the tools needed to build. In fact, till the latest update, I never faced difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem on Manjaro and I just solved it by installing the package `emacs-pdf-tools-git` from the AUR.